# How to resolve this Windows manager error in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am not able to understand what exectly happening here with the code.
My code sometimes running fine and sometimes not.

I am creating the bluetooth connection.I am searching for the devices when the search button is clicked. It gives me the list of devices and I am displaying it on the listview. This all working fine.

Now on the listItem click, I want to pair the my device with the selected device from the list.
I have used this code to do this.

```
   listViewDetected.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
            {
                Log.i("Log", "ListItem is clicked at :"+position);
                posn = position;
                String str = (String) listViewDetected.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Log.i("Log", "ListItem is :"+str);
                bluetoothDevice=arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
                final BluetoothDevice device = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
                Log.i("Log", "UUID string is :"+uid);
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        connect(device);
                    };
                }.start();
            }

            private void connect(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevicess) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("Log", "connect method after click: ");
                ParcelUuid[] uuids = servicesFromDevice(bluetoothDevicess);
                adapterPaired.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.i("Log", "service method executed");
            }
        });


public ParcelUuid[] servicesFromDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
        Log.i("Log", "service method is called ");
        Class cl = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Class[] par = {};
        Method method = cl.getMethod("createBond", par);
        Object[] args = {};
        ParcelUuid[] retval = (ParcelUuid[]) method.invoke(device, args);
        if(retval==null)
        {
            Log.i("Log", "GOT the Array as null:");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("Log", "GOT the Array:"+retval.length);
        }
        /* for(int i = 0;i<retval.length;i++)
        {               Log.i("Log", "GOT  :  "+retval[i]);
        }*/
        return retval;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Log", "Inside catch of serviceFromDevice Method");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Sometimes it is working very fine. but sometimes its not working.**

I repeat

**Sometimes it is working very fine. but sometimes its not working. Not even a single line is executing of listItem clicked() method.**

And I am getting this on logcat when its not working:

```
09-01 16:17:26.405: I/KeyInputQueue(171): Enqueueing touch event0
09-01 16:17:26.405: I/WindowManager(171): Read next event 0
09-01 16:17:26.405: I/WindowManager(171): Delivering pointer 0 > Window{4a6ea918 com.bdm/com.bdm.BluetoothDemo paused=false}
09-01 16:17:26.515: I/KeyInputQueue(171): Enqueueing touch event1
09-01 16:17:26.515: I/WindowManager(171): Read next event 1
09-01 16:17:26.515: I/WindowManager(171): Delivering pointer 1 > Window{4a6ea918 com.bdm/com.bdm.BluetoothDemo paused=false}
```

Comment: are you getting error in the code what you posted above in Question ..

Comment: actually i am handling all the pairing work on list item clicked. But when i am clicking then NOT EVEN a single log inside the void click() method is printing. And i am getting the above msg on logcat I posted

Comment: Where is the error line in log you have posted!?, please post it.

Comment: when it is working very fine and when bad ? I think simple posted code has not any warning and error! Because it is just simple and basically code!

Comment: See the edited code. And please let me know what is happening here. I am not able to understand why it run sometime and why it not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution of this problem. It was occurring just because of the Brodcast Receiver. I at the time i was clicking in the listItem,at the same time my receiver was getting triggerd. And in that i was calling the thread object. So that sometime, if at my thread was not called then listitem click was working fine. thanks for your interest friends. Thanks.